# Is there a feature that allows me to return the indice of a desired np array in another np array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Assume

```
Main_Array = np.array([[1,2], [3,4], [4,5], [5,6]])
```

Further assume

```
Object_Array = np.array([[1,2]])
```

I desire a function s.t.

```
f(Object_Array, Main_Array) = 0
```

I.e. the indice of the Objective_Array if i know that it is in the Main_Array. I can't seem to use `np.where()` as it is not vectorized. It does not look for arrays and when i try this in there i get weird results.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `Main_Array` and `Object_Array` is a list not numpy array.

Comment: " I can't seem to use np.where() as it is not vectorized." Huh?

Comment: You **must** provide a [mcve]. There are *no arrays here*, only `list` objects. If you are trying something, and it isn't working, *show us what you tried exactly and what it gives you*

Comment: `where` just finds the `True` values in its condition argument.  So it's only as good as the condition.  How are you trying compare the two arrays?  As simple `==`?  Have you looked at the resulting boolean array?

Comment: You'll find that Python rejects an expression like: `f(...) = 0`.  You cannot assign a value to a function.  You could do `Main_array[idx] =0` where `idx` is returned by your function.  Show us some of your attempts and the resulting errors or bad results.  That will give us a better idea of what you want, and where your misunderstandings occur.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`list.index`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/list/lindex.html):

```py
Main_Array = [[1,2], [3,4], [4,5], [5,6]]
Object_Array = [1,2]

Main_Array.index(Object_Array) # Outputs 0
```

Comment: The OP is almost certainly using `numpy.ndarray` objects, not `list` objects, despite their poor working example

Comment: Yep its numpy arrays. Sorry, for the confusion. So Main_Array = np.array([[1,2], [3,4], [4,5], [5,6]]) and the same for Object_Array

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question after quite a few attempts the following code works:

```
index = np.where(np.all(Main_Array == Objective_Array, axis = 1))
```

then the folowing result is reached

```
index == [[0]]
```

and the desired value can be attained by:

```
index[0][0] == 0
```

If there were no matches it would give:

```
index == [[]]
```

So we can use len(index[0]) as a condition for statements since Objective_Array in Main_Array statement usually results in a false positive. If Object_Array were not in main array we would have:

```
len(index[0]) == 0
```

If it is in the array we get:

```
len(index[0]) > 0
```

In our particular case we had:

```
len(index[0]) == 1
```